# How to add a variable to an a href selector in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm trying to add a selected class to a post in ruby on rails.

When I insert `loc` into the query `a[href` selector it doesn't work even though `loc` is giving the correct url.

```
$(document).ready ->
    jQuery ->
        loc = location.href.substring(7)
        loc = loc.substring(loc.indexOf("/"))
        $('a[href$="posts?page=6"]').addClass("selected");
```

I want to put loc into the selector, like this
`$('a[href$=""+loc]').addClass("selected");`

But it's not applying the selected class. Any help?

Comment: What you are doing seems basically correct. Hard to tell without your html. - http://jsfiddle.net/NjcSQ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basic JavaScript string concatenation:

```
var loc = "6";
'a[href$=""+loc]'    //-> 'a[href$=""+loc]'  oops
'a[href$="'+loc+'"]' //-> 'a[href$="6"]'     yay!
```

Answer (score 3):

CoffeeScript has string interpolation, so you can do this:

```
$("a[href$='#{loc}']").addClass("selected")
```